# Connecting Google Cloud SQL from a different host php

Tags: php, mysql, google-cloud-platform

I'm new to Google Cloud, created MySQL instance and setup database and user account.

Now my code is on a different host, I added IP address of my code host in my GCP Connections section.

I'm able to connect to this database from MySQL Workbench but I'm unable to connect to it using PHP.

I'm writing a simple PDO:

```
$db = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname, $port);
```

but its returning me this error `(2002) Connection refused`.

I'm not sure where its going wrong.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct mysql port in the code.

Comment: Edit your question. 1) Show how you setup the address whitelisting in Google Cloud SQL. 2) What are the values for $servername and $port? 4) Is MySQL Workbench running on the same machine as your code?

Comment: Note: I recommend that you set up Cloud SQL Proxy and not use direct IP based access.

Comment: Note: Connection Refused means nobody is listening for your connections. This means that either the IP address or the Port or both is wrong OR the Cloud SQL Firewall is blocking you.

Answer (score 0):

Connecting external applications to Cloud SQL can be done [using the proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app#proxy) or by [configuring access for public IP connections](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app#appaccessIP).

If the host is on a Paas application or service (among others), it’s possible that the [IP address is dynamically assigned](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app#dynamicIP) which means it would be ephemeral. In this case, the best solution would be to [connect by using the proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app#proxy).

If following these methods and references still fail, then details about how the address whitelisting was performed is needed, along a verification of the $servername and $port values.